# Solve single variable equation using if, else and while statements in python

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am tutoring a 7th grade student in basic programming and mathematics. One of the problems the students needs to complete for a class assignment is "create a program to solve a given single variable linear equation". The student is required to use python and only use `if`, `else` and `while` statements. The program can include user defined functions and lists but cannot import any libraries like regex, sympy, numpy, etc.

The program should be able to solve these example equations:

- 2*x - 5 = 8
- 4*x + 3 = 3*x - 10
- 11*x = 2 - (1/5)*x
- 4*(x + 2) = 5*(x + 9)

I tried: For each character in the string note the numerals, operators, equals to sign and variable. Copy the variable and its coefficient into a new string and the constants with their signs to another string. My hope was that I would eventually extract the integers from each string and solve the equation for `x`. But I wasn't correctly capturing numbers with multiple digits. And the equation with parentheses completely stumped me. Not being able to use regex or sympy is painful!

I am looking for a pythonic solution to this problem if it exists.

I feel this is a very difficult question for a 7th grader because my grad and undergrad friends haven't been able to come up with a solution. Any advice on how to proceed will help if a programmatic solution isn't available.

Thank you.

Comment: "I feel this is a very difficult question for a 7th grader"—agreed, especially under the "only use`if`, `else`, and `while` statements" constraint, unless the scope is artificially limited in some significant way. Where did this assignment come from?

Comment: This would need to write a small parser for processing the expression first, creating a syntax tree which can then be modified to solve the equation and write it out. This needs a lot of knowledge.

Comment: @Chris the student's teacher gave this assignment which is due Nov 1. The student and his classmates are struggling. Sadly I am struggling more than them to comprehend this teacher's methods.

Comment: IMO even asking them to compute the result of a mathematical expression like `2 * (3 + 4)`, given as a string, would be pushing what's reasonable at that age unless the goal is to use `eval()`—a dangerous lesson, especially for new programmers. Constraining them to `if`, `else`, and `while` makes it quite difficult. (Though to be fair, the last group of high school students I supervised at a hackathon were doing very impressive work, far beyond what I was doing at that age). Solving an equation is orders of magnitude harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is completely possible to build a finite automaton solve an expression, it is not an easy task.

I myself had lots of assignments related to build a semantic or syntax parser, but it is usually done in C: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112620/simple-expression-calculator-in-c.

Nonetheless, if you accept a clever/dangerous/bad-practice solution:

```
def solve_expression(expr, var="x"):
    expr = expr.replace(var, "1j")
    left, right = map(eval, expr.split("="))

    return (right.real-left.real)/(left.imag-right.imag)

print(solve_expression("2*x - 5 = 8"))
print(solve_expression("4*x + 3 = 3*x - 10"))
print(solve_expression("11*x = 2 - (1/5)*x"))
print(solve_expression("4*(x + 2) = 5*(x + 9)"))
```

The idea is to convert the free variable to the imaginary unit and let python interpreter do the rest.

Comment: wow brilliant solution. I'll accept it. Though it isn't what I can explain to a 7th grader who is learning about basic algebra. Python interpreter has `eval` expression that can do a great deal but such functions weren't allowed. My conclusion is that the assignment was inappropriately framed.

Comment: @samkhan13, furthermore, `eval()` is both _extremely dangerous_ and _extremely powerful_. Asking new programmers to use it is akin to giving new apprentice construction workers a jackhammer before giving them a pickaxe. The jackhammer may be necessary in some circumstances but without having mastered the pickaxe the jackhammer is going to be used in places where it's massive overkill and unsafe.